# Selenium - unable to locate element by classname

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to find a `p` tag with `class = "big-number"`. Here is the code I wrote:

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("big-number")));
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
System.out.println(myDynamicElement);
```

Here is my output:

```
[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (fed46ad4-9ca9-9344-a57a-1d336db3927c)] -> class name: big-number]
```

I cannot identify the error, it is giving me an output but its makes no sense to me. 
Any tips on how I can at least identify my error?

I am certainly sure the element is present, here is the HTML code:

```
    <div id="users-online-container" style="">
        <img class="big-number-icon" src="images/usersOnline.png">
        <p class="big-number">228</p>
        <p class="caption">Users Online</p>
    </div>
    <div id="users-online-loading"></div>
```

Comment: Posting a bit more of the stack trace and error message would help. Also, does you element have multiple classes?

Comment: There are two more elements with the same class. Here is a sample <p class="big-number"> 45 </p> <p class="big-number">55</p>

Comment: There is no error , the output is what I provided. If I change to HtmlUnitDriver, I am getting an error. I'll post what the error is

Comment: Was the edit helpful for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TimeOutException occurs because driver cannot find element in specific time. Problem in selector i think. If you sure that element always visible, and exists on the page so try next code:

```
//Select first paragraph in div
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#users-online-container .big-number"));
//if you have several p with same classes you could access any of them using index. e.g.
driver.findElements(By.CssSelector(".big-number"))[index];
```

Selectors can be `#users-online-container .big-number` or `.big-number`. Both will work.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply! I will use the CSS Selector now more often cause I think it is much simpler than having to declare two web elements. I found my error I didn't have a .getText() . IT gives me some address w/o .getText() strange cause I didn't see any tutorials containing that. Anyways, my error was solved and thanks for taking your time to reply

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..

```
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("big-number")));

// It will print the text of the Element:
system.out.println(myDynamicElement.getText());
```

Also you try to locate the element with the help of XPATH and make sure your locator is uniquely identify the element. Also check that IsDisplayed() and IsEnabled() returns True.

In your code you are printing the WebElement that will print the Hashcode.
In order to get the text of the Element, you'll have to use getText() method.

Hope it will help!